# Install ignored files with NPM

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

The package is listed in project dependencies:

```
  "name": "project",
  "devDependencies": {
    "package": "*"
  }
```

Some of the files in installed package are ignored by blacklisting (`.npmignore`) or by whitelisting:

```
  "name": "package",
  "files": [
    "lib/",
    "index.js",
    "LICENSE",
    "README.md"
  ],
```

Forking it and changing ignore settings is not an option for me. I would prefer to have it in `node_modules` and `require` it like normal package, and doing things like `git clone` in npm `install` script looks like a terrible idea because it is dev dependency and shouldn't be installed for users who add `project` as a dependency.

Can `package` repo be installed entirely on `npm i`, including ignored files? What are the options?