# Make my NPM package available in source and dist versions

Tags: git, npm

I am working on a private NPM package that I make available to developers who use our API.  For various reasons (decided by management), the package on our NPM repository (Sonatype Nexus) has the following folder structure:

```
+- build
| |- browser.min.js
| \- node.min.js
|- docs
| \ ...
|- package.json
\- README.md
```

The JS files in the `build` directory are compiled from the actual code of the package.

Also included in the built package are specific versions of dependencies that the package relies on (such as a modified version of [`WildEmitter`](https://github.com/HenrikJoreteg/wildemitter)).

To allow for easy publishing, the `package.json` has the following in it:

```
  ...
  "main": "build/node.min.js",
  "browser": "build/browser.min.js",
  "files": [
    "build/*.js",
    "docs/*",
    "README.md"
  ],
  ...
```

However, for internal use of the package, we want to use an uncompiled version, specifically to reduce the overhead of included our dependencies that were included above.

(Aside, I know that this isn't necessarily the best way to package stuff, but we can't change that so easily at this point unless we have no other option.)

I assumed that I would be able to pull the package from our private Git repository, which would give me the whole code of the package.

However, NPM still reads the `files` section of `package.json` when it loads from Git, so it does the `git clone` and then *deletes* any files that are not present in the `files` array, leaving me with a directory that contains only `docs/*`, `package.json`, and `README.md`.

Is there a way to get the entire code of the package checked out of Git and kept?

Comment: Related, but I don't think duplicate (because here I control both sides and *can* modify the package if needed): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35446639/install-ignored-files-with-npm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I decided to modify my build process to make this easier.

Instead of building just the scipts into the `build` directory and packaging starting from the repository root directory, I have modified my build script to also copy `README.md`, `package.json`, and `docs/*` into the `build` directory, then to `cd` into that directory to do the `npm publish`.

That way, `package.json` can just say to include all files in the directory.